# Strapi Content Type has relation with user Model not return user data on request

Tags: reactjs, strapi, headless-cms

I have a response content type that has a relationship with the user from the user-permission model. when I request through POSTMAN I just get the answer field not the user field however in Strapi v3 while sending the request it gives me both fields.
[image: Response content type]

postman result
[image: Postman result]

any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after searching I found that this is a bug in Strapi v4 and still there is no way to populate user from the user-permissions modal.

Github bug report =>
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11957